# Accessing Maven Pom Variables From Properties File

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-plugin-development

I am developing a custom maven plugin. When I write:

```
${project.version}
```

into my pom file I can get its value however is there a way if I write into a properties file:

```
project.version = ${project.version}
```

that will set the project.version value correctly, how can I implement it at my Java code?

**PS:** I don't use annotations at my Mojo and I don't want to use variables at my Java code because user should define as my variables as at a properties file and I can not change my core Java code in order to changed things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Maven resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) by simply adding `<resources>` inside `<build>` and turning on filtering for anything you want.

Comment: Any hints on how to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56173541/access-file-path-from-properties-file-in-maven-while-running-junit ?

Answer (score 0):

within your mojo if using annotations see http://maven.apache.org/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-plugin/examples/using-annotations.html
use

```
@Component
protected MavenProject project;
```

with doclet

```
/**
 * The Maven project to act upon.
 * 
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @required
 */
private MavenProject project;
```

then project.getVersion()

Comment: It means I should define a new variable for every new entry at properties file. For a pom file maven replaces that expressions and I want to do that job at my plugin and read from a properties file and get the value of expression or I wamt to let it maven to get me the value of an expression(without using any other plugin because I am developing mine) at a properties file?

Comment: That was the way to get MavenProject in a maven plugin. If you want to do some filtering on files like the resources plugin do you must have a look at the component http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-filtering/

Comment: is there an example how to use it?

Comment: it writes everything into another directory is there anything to avoid it?

Comment: you can configure http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.4/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Resource.html with some includes and/or excludes to select which resources.

Comment: can you check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14774667/mavenresourcesexecution-how-to-get-as-variable-instead-of-writing-to-a-file I don't want a new file at my project, I want to get the thing inside output file?

Comment: also this can be better if you see that conversation: Custom Resource Filter Implementation http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Reading-Variables-From-a-Properties-File-Without-Creating-An-Ouptut-File-td5746409.html

Answer (score 0):

You may read and save any property in your `pom.xml` as i do in this function:

```
/**
 * Save a property in a pom.xml
 *
 * @param propertyName Name of the property
 * @param value New value for the property
 */
public static void saveProjectProperty(String propertyName, String value)
{
    Model model = null;
    FileReader reader = null;
    MavenXpp3Reader mavenreader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
    try
    {
        reader = new FileReader("pom.xml");
        model = mavenreader.read(reader);
        MavenProject project = new MavenProject(model);
        while (project.getParent() != null)
        {
            project = project.getParent();
        }
        project.getProperties().put(propertyName, value);
        try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("pom.xml"))
        {
            project.writeModel(fileWriter);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        LOG.severe("Error saving pom.xml");
    }
    catch (XmlPullParserException ex)
    {
        LOG.warning("Error reading pom.xml");
    }
}
```

To be able to use the clases not native in the JVM you should add these dependencies:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency
```