# Get Maven basedir from a properties file in a SpringBoot project

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, junit, properties-file

The Maven project I inherited has some resource files used in JUnits.
Those files are referred in a properties file as absolute paths.
Let's assume the Maven project is under `myproject`, where the main `pom.xml` resides.

A `config.properties` file has:

```
keystore.file=C:/Users/tom/myproject/web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks
```

I want to refer to that resource from a relative path of the Maven project.
So I have been trying something like:

```
keystore.file=${project.basedir}/web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks
```

I have been reading about [resource filtering](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) which is referred in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763431/accessing-maven-pom-variables-from-properties-file).

The project uses SpringBoot, and when running a JUnit, complains with:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'project.basedir' in string value "${project.basedir}/web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks"
    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:174)
```

Comment: what did you mean 'With no good results.' ? what is actual result?

Comment: Can you try like this keystore.file=./web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks. It is from current directory.

Comment: @nephewtom could you point me on the your structure of maven projects? I have added the example here https://github.com/sbzDev/stackoverflow/tree/master/question56173541

Comment: @SergeyBzhezitskiy I mean that running a JUnit fails to understand the file path, whereas with the absolute path it works.

Comment: @SergeyBzhezitskiy Well, the real project has one more level. It has `myproject/pom.xml` and `myproject/web/pom.xml`, which is where the JUnits reside.

Comment: @Sambit I already tested that and reports: `Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: .\web\src\test\resources\myfile.jks (The system cannot find the path specified)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
`

Answer (score 9):

After trying different things, found a solution to my problem.
Adding this line in Spring Boot `application.properties`:

```
maven.basedir=@project.basedir@
```

And then in `config.properties`:

```
keystore.file=${maven.basedir}/web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks
```

Makes it work.
Check: [Spring Boot automatic Property Expansion Using Maven.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven)

Comment: I tried using the same in bootstrap.yml file, getting the exception `Caused by: while scanning for the next token
found character '@' that cannot start any token. (Do not use @ for indentation)`. Is there any solution for this issue?

Comment: Do not know, sorry.