# How in properties get the path of file from test resource in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, properties

I have hardcoded path to the jsk file in properties file, which is use during unit tests running:

`file.tls.keystore.path=/opt/jks/client-cert.jks`

This force everyone to copy this file to specific place to execute the unit tests. I would like to copy this file to the test resources (`src/test`resources`) and get it as path.

But how can I do this? I was trying `${project.build.testDirectory}`(I know that test resources != testDirecotry) but it does not work. In the exception I still see:

```
Value: "${project.build.sourceDirectory}/jks/client-cert.jks"
```

which means, when I start test, placeholder was not setup.

I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56183453/865448

```
After trying different things, found a solution to my problem.
Adding this line in Spring Boot application.properties:

maven.basedir=@project.basedir@

And then in config.properties:

keystore.file=${maven.basedir}/web/src/test/resources/myfile.jks
```

But the result is same. So my question, is it possible to achieve this? Via maven? Any help/tip much appreciate! Is it possible with yml instead of properties?

Comment: Don't. Use `classpath:/opt/jks/client-cert.jks` as the path and put the jsk file in `src/test/resources`. Then when inject this use a `Resource` insteda of what you have now (a String or the like).

Comment: I can not change this, this is consume by external dependency, which expect path.

Comment: Then override it for testing. You are already changing it so why is this change not possible? If it is a property that cannot be changed what is the use of a property in the first place?